# Need insights about writing a pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

For my source code, I have the following IR:

```
; ModuleID = '<stdin>'


@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [9 x i8] c"SOME_ENV_VAR\00", align 1
@.str1 = private unnamed_addr constant [26 x i8] c"Need to set $ENV_Variable.\0A\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define void @foo(i8* %bar) #0 {
entry:
  %bar.addr = alloca i8*, align 4
  %baz = alloca i8*, align 4
  store i8* %bar, i8** %bar.addr, align 4
  %call = call i8* @getenv(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([9 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0)) #2
  store i8* %call, i8** %baz, align 4
  %0 = load i8** %baz, align 4
  %cmp = icmp eq i8* %0, null
  br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.else

if.then:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %call1 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([26 x i8]* @.str1, i32 0, i32 0))
  br label %if.end

if.else:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %1 = load i8** %bar.addr, align 4
  %2 = load i8** %baz, align 4
  %call2 = call i8* @strcpy(i8* %1, i8* %2) #2
  br label %if.end

if.end:                                           ; preds = %if.else, %if.then
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare i8* @getenv(i8*) #0

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #1

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare i8* @strcpy(i8*, i8*) #0
```

I intend to write a **pass**, which when compiled (using **LLVM**), produces bitcode where the call to strcpy(dest,src) is replaced with strncpy(dest,src,n).

I've written the following code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/PassManager.h"
#include "llvm/Analysis/Verifier.h"
#include "llvm/Assembly/PrintModulePass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"

using namespace llvm;
namespace
{
Module* makeLLVMModule() {


    Module* mod = new Module(llvm::StringRef("CustomPass"),getGlobalContext());

    Constant* c = mod->getOrInsertFunction(llvm::StringRef("foo"),Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()),NULL); 

    Function* foo = cast<Function>(c);
    Function::arg_iterator args =foo->arg_begin();
    Value* bar = args++;

    BasicBlock* Entry = BasicBlock::Create(getGlobalContext(),llvm::Twine("Entry"), foo);
    BasicBlock* False = BasicBlock::Create(getGlobalContext(),llvm::Twine("False"), foo);
    BasicBlock* True = BasicBlock::Create(getGlobalContext(),llvm::Twine("True"), foo);

    char* pPath;
    pPath = getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR");

    IRBuilder<> builder(Entry);
    Value* envVarDoesntExist = builder.CreateICmpEQ(llvm::StringRef(pPath),Constant::getNullValue(Value),llvm::Twine("temp"));
    //---1
    builder.CreateCondBr(envVarDoesntExist, False, True);

    builder.SetInsertPoint(True);
    builder.CreateCall3(strncpy,bar,llvm::StringRef(pPath),45,llvm::Twine("temp"));
    //---2 

    builder.SetInsertPoint(False);
    builder.CreateCall(printf,llvm::StringRef("Need to set $ENV_Variable.\n"),llvm::Twine("temp"));
    //---1
    return mod;        

    }

}

char funcP::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<funcP> X("funcp", "funcP", false, false);
```

1. From ---1:How to convert llvm::StringRef to Value* ?
2. From ---2:How to convert char* to Value*
3. Could `Constant::getNullValue(Value)` be used for getting a NULL value?

Comment: You have multiple mistakes here, but beyond that you write that the goal of the pass is "the call to strcpy(dest,src) is replaced with strncpy(dest,src,n)". But that's not what you are trying to do at all - you are trying to create the entire flow (check the env var, branch based of it, and either insert a call to printf or to strncpy). Could you clarify what the goal of the pass is?

Comment: The idea behind writing the pass is to ensure that strncpy() is called instead of strcpy() - i.e. whenever foo() is invoked. Should I not be creating a new flow?

Comment: @Oak I'm new to LLVM, any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing, even so, I'm still grappling with the concepts.
If there is another way through which I can get the expected result, it would really help to know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I intend to write a pass, which when compiled (using LLVM), produces bitcode where the call to strcpy(dest,src) is replaced with strncpy(dest,src,n).

Then what you need to do is to locate the call instruction and change it. There's no need to recreate the entire flow, it's already in your source code.

All you need to do is to [create a function pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html), [iterate over all the instructions in the function](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-the-instruction-in-a-function), and [if the instruction](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates) is a [call instruction](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html) and the callee's name is `strcpy` then create a new call instruction to your new function, then [replace](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a58cb353f6bb490b0c689f5f2a830414d) the old instruction with the new instruction.

Also there seems to be some fundamental misunderstanding in your code between values in the compiler (such as `45` and all the `StringRef`s) and values in the code you are processing (instances of one of the subtypes of `llvm::Value`). Specifically, you can't just use `45` as a parameter to a function in the code you are processing - you have to [create a constant int](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html#a1c51933b9fb89c364a098fad544cba96) from that number, and then you can use that constant.

One final note - you can [implicitly construct](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/StringRef_8h_source.html#l00076) a `StringRef` from a `const char*`, you don't need to explicitly call the `StringRef`'s constructor all over the place. [Same with `Twine`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Twine_8h_source.html#l00263).